# Extract data from variable based on column heading in R

Tags: r, data-processing

I would like to be able to do the following based on the example dataset below in R (the actual dataset is much longer with many more years for addresses):

```
|ID|birthyr   |address1990|address1991|address1992|address1993|
|A |1992      |NA         |NA         |2          |2          |
|B |1990      |2          |2          |3          |3          |
|C |1991      |NA         |3          |3          |1          |
```

I want to make a new column with the address value for the year they were born in. So ideally I would take the year in `birthyr` for each person and look to see which column heading contains this string and then use the value in that column for that person. I have a way of doing this at the moment, see below code, however it is not the best method as it takes the value from the first column of addresses in which data is present and I'm concerned that this may result in missing data.

```
#dat is the dataset

#add empty columns that new values will go in
dat$birth_address<-NA
dat$address_first_year<-NA

#Take first value from address column which contains data and add the value to  birth address and then add the column name to the column address_first_year
J<-seq(3,6,by=1)
for(i in 1:dim(dat)[1]){
    for(j in J){
        if(!is.na(dat[i,j])){
            dat$birth_address[i]<-dat[i,j]
            dat$address_first_year[i]<-names(dat)[j]
            break
        }
    }
}

#remove string from address_first_year column and change years to numeric
dat$address_first_year<-sub("address", "", dat$address_first_year)
dat$address_first_year<-as.numeric(dat$address_first_year)

#remove rows where address_first_year is not equal to birthyr to ensure that values in new column are actually from birthyr
for(i in 1:dim(dat)[1]){
    if(dat$address_first_year[i] != dat$birthyr[i]){
        dat$birth_address[i]<-NA
    }
}
```

When running the above code on the example I get the following results. Although this gives me what I want I imagine there are circumstances when it would not, hence I wanted a more succinct and robust way of doing this.

```
  ID birthyr address1990 address1991 address1992 address1993 birth_address address_first_year
1  A    1992          NA          NA           2           2             2               1992
2  B    1990           2           2           3           3             2               1990
3  C    1991          NA           3           3           1             3               1991
```

EDIT:- updated as per comments below
These are the results I get with the code below, but it does not seem to be what I would expect.

```
  ID birthyr address1990 address1991 address1992 address1993 birth_address
1  A    1992          NA          NA           2           2             2
2  B    1990           2           2           3           3             3
3  C    1991          NA           3           3           1             2
```

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful to post the result of `dput(dat)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply I think I have added what you requested, let me know if that is not the case

Answer (score 2):

Given that `dat` is your data and using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  gather(addressYY, value, 3:6) %>% 
  mutate(BirthAdderess = gsub(x = addressYY, 'address', '')) %>% 
  filter(birthyr == BirthAdderess)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm quite new to R and I'm not entirely sure what the above does. Are you able to give a brief explanation please?

Comment: Sure. With the `gather` function we trasform the addressYear columns in rows with the address value, with `mutate` and `gsub` we transform all the text like `address1990` in numbers and then we filter only those rows where the birth year is the same as the adressYear.
You can execute it line by line to get what it does.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However ideally I would like to keep the original addressYY columns as I will need them later on. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The best course of action using this solution would be to merge the original df to the results using `merge()`. 
With the knowledge that this has to be attached to the original df someone will probably find a better solution.. this feels 'hacky'

Comment: No, I like this. Add `%>% collect %>% .[["value"]]` to the end and `dat$birth_address <- ` to the beginning and this looks fairly robust.

Comment: @K.Daisey I am not familiar with the above notation. In the OP's example, how would it fit? Add it to the end of where and the beginning of where?

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm also not sure how you would add each part to the code... sorry I'm not at all familiar with the %>%  notation so I think that's why I'm having a problem understanding it fully

Comment: @VisionIncision `collect` is from `dplyr` and creates a dataframe of the columns specified. `.[["value"]]` returns a vector of the values in column `value` of that dataframe. `dat$birthaddress <- ` is placed at the beginning of the chained statement so it reads `dat$birthaddress <- dat %>%` and assigns the output (the vector of value results) to a column in dat named 'birthaddress'.

Comment: @user5481267 `%>%` signifies chaining or 'piping'. The documentation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/652/pipe-operators-and-others#t=201702091528469769179) is a nice introduction. Basically, instead of nesting functions inside of functions, you can chain them for easier readability.
Say you have `1:3` and you want to turn it into `1.2.3` and print that statement. You might use `print(paste(1:3, collapse = "."))` or `t <- paste(1:3, collapse = ".")`, but this can get confusing and it is opposite how we think. Instead you can write `1:3 %>% paste(collapse = ".") %>% print`.

Comment: @K.Daisey Apologies for the delay in replying, I have been away. So I tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why but I have updated the question to include the output I get with this.

Comment: @user5481267 the order is different in the df created. Try `dat2 <- dat %>% 
  gather(addressYY, value, 3:6) %>% 
  mutate(BirthAdderess = gsub(x = addressYY, 'address', '')) %>% 
  filter(birthyr == BirthAdderess) %>%
  right_join(y = dat, by = "ID")` instead.